# How to define URI pattern for a GET request with multiple parameters of the same type

Tags: java, rest, get, jersey

I would like to create a uri for a `GET` request that has multiple values for a single key for example the key `mykey` can have values a,b,c,d sent within the same `URI`.

How can I do that so that it will work with `Jersey` in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to invent a split character which is never contained in your actual values and split the combined parameter at the split character.

Comment: For example, yes, but be aware of potential URL parameter encoding.

Comment: Any resources regarding that?